# Python plot side by side with axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I haven't seen a setup like this and appreciate the guidance here -

I have multiple bar plots (each day of the week) and I would like to display them side by side with the labels (using the label function). Right now, only the first chart plots the labels.

```
plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax = df[df.day_of_week=='Fri'].groupby('date').agg('amount').mean().plot(ax=ax1,kind='bar',x='date',y='amount')

# code for labels
def add_value_labels(plot,spacing=7):
    for rect in ax.patches:
        # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
        y = rect.get_height()
        x = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
        space = spacing
        va = 'bottom'
        # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
        if y < 0:
            # Invert space to place label below
            space *= -1
            # Vertically align label at top
            va = 'top'
            
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y)

        # Create annotation
        ax.annotate(
            label,                     
            (x, y),         
            xytext=(0, space),          
            textcoords="offset points", 
            ha='center',               
            va=va)                  

add_value_labels(ax)

bx1=plt.subplot(222)
bx = df[df.day_of_week=='Sat'].groupby('date').agg('amount').mean().plot(ax=bx1,kind='bar',x='date',y='amount')
add_value_labels(bx)
```

How can I display these two plots side by side, with both label functions working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method `add_value_labels`, `plot` is given as an argument. However, you are working with `ax` inside the method, so it will always work on the `ax object` defined outside of the function, which is your first plot (only). If you replace `ax` with `plot` it should work. Here is my code with some basic example data.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame([["1.1.20", "Fri", 15], ["2.1.20", "Sat", 20], ["3.1.20", "Fri", -2], ["4.1.20","Sat", 2]], columns=["date","day_of_week","amount"])

plt.figure(1)
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
ax = df[df.day_of_week=='Fri'].groupby('date').agg('amount').mean().plot(ax=ax1,kind='bar',x='date',y='amount')

# code for labels

def add_value_labels(plot,spacing=7):
    for rect in plot.patches:
        # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
        y = rect.get_height()
        x = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
        space = spacing
        va = 'bottom'
        # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
        if y < 0:
            # Invert space to place label below
            space *= -1
            # Vertically align label at top
            va = 'top'
            
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y)

        # Create annotation
        plot.annotate(
            label,                     
            (x, y),         
            xytext=(0, space),          
            textcoords="offset points", 
            ha='center',               
            va=va)            
        
add_value_labels(ax)

bx1=plt.subplot(222)
bx = df[df.day_of_week=='Sat'].groupby('date').agg('amount').mean().plot(ax=bx1,kind='bar',x='date',y='amount')
add_value_labels(bx)
```